# Ubuntu 18.04, systemd-networkd, DHCP and requesting 192.168.0.2 from DHCP server

Tags: networking, 18.04, dhcp

I'm using systemd to configure two network interfaces. One using DHCP and another with static IP(v4 address).

```
# systemctl --version
systemd 237
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

I'm using the following network configuration:

eth0:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/network/lan0.network
[Match]
    Name=eth0
[Network]
    DHCP=ipv4
    LLDP=no
[DHCP]
    ClientIdentifier=mac
```

eth1:

```
 # cat /etc/systemd/network/lan1.network
 [Match]
    Name=eth1
 [Link]
    RequiredForOnline=no
 [Network]
    ConfigureWithoutCarrier=true
    Address=192.168.1.2/24
```

Bootloader (grup options to the kernel):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1 net.ifnames=1 biosdevname=0"
```

which disable IPv6 and enable old school device names.

```
# journalctl -b -u systemd-networkd
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: Flags change: +LOWER_UP +RUNNING
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: Gained carrier
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: Acquiring DHCPv4 lease
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x70153129): STARTED on ifindex 2
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properti
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x70153129): DISCOVER
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x70153129): OFFER
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x70153129): REQUEST (requesting)
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x70153129): ACK
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x70153129): lease expires in 57s
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x70153129): T2 expires in 50s
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x70153129): T1 expires in 29s
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.0.2/24 via 192.168.0.100
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: Updating address: 192.168.0.2/24 (valid for 1min)
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properti
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: DHCP error: could not get routes: No data available
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: Configured
Aug 06 14:01:52 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus
Aug 06 14:02:22 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x70153129): REQUEST (renewing)
Aug 06 14:02:43 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x70153129): REQUEST (rebinding)
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x70153129): EXPIRED
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: DHCP lease lost
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: Removing address 192.168.0.2
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x13958afa): DISCOVER
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: Removing address: 192.168.0.2/24 (valid for 3s)
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properti
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x13958afa): OFFER
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x13958afa): REQUEST (requesting)
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x13958afa): ACK
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x13958afa): lease expires in 9min 57s
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x13958afa): T2 expires in 8min 43s
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: DHCP CLIENT (0x13958afa): T1 expires in 4min 59s
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 10.0.0.98/24 via 10.0.0.1
Aug 06 14:02:49 testpcdk458 systemd-networkd[518]: eth0: Updating address: 10.0.0.98/24 (valid for 10min)
```

Why is the DHCP client trying to request 192.168.0.2 twice? Where does this come from? The DHCP server finally gives 10.0.0.98 as specified in its configuration, but this is a waste of time.

This is a test system and I need it to start quickly. The problem is not functional, but how long it takes to configure the interface using DHCP.

Edit:

Requested info:

```
 # ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
```

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jul 12 12:50 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

```
 # ls -al /etc/netplan/
 total 16
 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug  5 14:05 .
 drwxr-xr-x 131 root root 12288 Aug  6 13:11 ..
```

Comment: May we see: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Please edit your question to show the results.

Comment: chilli555, thanks for looking into this. :) I updated the question.

Comment: Typically, networking in Ubuntu Server 18.04 et seq is handled by netplan. You seem to have removed it in favor of /etc/systemd/network/xxx. Did you follow a tutorial or howto? I am not surprised that it doesn't work as expected. If you have a link, may we see it?

Comment: There are 3 ways to setup networking in Ubuntu. This is desktop btw. Netplan is one and it is not required and doesn't work with renaming ethernet devices using udev.